# How to make table row clickable while using <display:table> &<display:column>

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, clickable

```
<display:table class="table" name="regionList" id="elem"
        requestURI="./addCountry.html">
        <display:column property="name" title="Country" />
        <display:column property="code" title="City" />
        <display:column title="&nbsp;">
            <a href="QQQQ.html?id=<c:out value='${elem.id}' />">Edit</a>
        </display:column>
    </display:table>
```

How can I make the whole table row clickable as link?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 options here:

1. Wrap het div's within anchor (Not best practice and i don't think seo likes it)
2. `$(".parentdiv").click(function() {
      window.location = $(this).data("http:///www.location.com");
   });`
3. `<div onclick="location.href='YOUR-URL-HERE';" style="cursor: pointer;"></div>`

Comment: Thanks Man, But this will make the whole div clickable. I just want to make the rows clickable.....

Comment: Then you should probably go for option 3?
And the onclick location within the row and add cursor iwht css

Comment: Yes, This way is in my mind. I wanted to do it dynamically. Like in a JS function, the url call will be handled associated with the respective ID (Long value from DB) from each table row.

Comment: Well, it takes kind of a different approach.... Did you succeed in getting the right data from the database and looping through this?
If so add your code to the startpost.